# How do I speed up this Django PostgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I'm trying to speed up what seems to me to be quite a slow PostgreSQL query in Django (150ms)

This is the query:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "predictions_prediction"
INNER JOIN "minute_in_time_minute"
ON ( "predictions_prediction"."minute_id" = "minute_in_time_minute"."id" )
WHERE ("minute_in_time_minute"."datetime" >= '2014-08-21 13:12:00+00:00'
AND "predictions_prediction"."location_id" = 1
AND "minute_in_time_minute"."datetime" < '2014-08-24 13:12:00+00:00'
AND "predictions_prediction"."tide_level" >= 3.0)
ORDER BY "minute_in_time_minute"."datetime" ASC
```

Here's the result of the PostgreSQL EXPLAIN:

```
Sort  (cost=17731.45..17739.78 rows=3331 width=32) (actual time=151.755..151.901 rows=3515 loops=1)
  Sort Key: minute_in_time_minute.datetime
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 371kB
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3187.44..17536.56 rows=3331 width=32) (actual time=96.757..150.693 rows=3515 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (predictions_prediction.minute_id = minute_in_time_minute.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on predictions_prediction  (cost=0.00..11232.00 rows=411175 width=20) (actual time=0.017..88.063 rows=410125 loops=1)
              Filter: ((tide_level >= 3::double precision) AND (location_id = 1))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 115475
        ->  Hash  (cost=3134.21..3134.21 rows=4258 width=12) (actual time=9.221..9.221 rows=4320 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 203kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on minute_in_time_minute  (cost=92.07..3134.21 rows=4258 width=12) (actual time=1.147..8.220 rows=4320 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((datetime >= '2014-08-21 13:18:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (datetime < '2014-08-24 13:18:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on minute_in_time_minute_datetime_key  (cost=0.00..91.00 rows=4258 width=0) (actual time=0.851..0.851 rows=4320 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((datetime >= '2014-08-21 13:18:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (datetime < '2014-08-24 13:18:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
```

I've tried visualising it in an external tool (http://explain.depesz.com/s/CWW) which shows that the start of the problem is the `Seq Scan on predictions_prediction`

What I've tried so far:

- Add an index on `predictions_prediction.tide_level`
- Add a composite index on `tide_level` and `location` on `predictions.prediction`

But neither had any effect as far as I could see.

Can someone please help me interpret the query plan?

Thanks

Comment: You have to avoid the >= and <= for better performance. If you can, try to add more columns to your table and another table with the values you need so you can replace >= and <= with an =. Look for OLAP model.

Comment: Oh! Presumably that applies to `>` and `<` too?

Comment: You *do* have an index on `prediction.minute_id` don't you? And that column has the same type as `minute.id`?

Comment: @RichardHuxton It's a Django ForeignKey which, according to the docs, will have an index unless you disable it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the following composite index on predictions_prediction

```
(minute_id, location_id, tide_level)
```

150ms for this type of query (a join, several where conditions with inequalities and an order by) is actually relatively normal, so you might not be able to speed it up much more.

Comment: @lalborno that's why `tide_level` where `>=` is being used, is the last part of the key.

Comment: This had a small effect - it reduced the query time from ~150 to ~135ms :)

Comment: @PaulMFurley does the new query plan still do a seq scan on predictions_prediction? btw i didn't notice that the query only takes 150ms - that's actually not very slow